# Stata: graph soldiers deployed at any given time

Tags: graph, stata

I would like to create a timeline of the number of soldiers deployed abroad at any given time.

```
Operation      Start         End            Soldiers
Operation 1    24.03.1999    14.01.2001     447
Operation 2    15.05.2004    03.03.2009     880
Operation 3    19.12.2006    24.01.2014     4390
```

For simplicity, I assume that the number of soldiers deployed in an operation was constant over time.

However, we cannot assume that all soldiers were deployed at the same time and stayed for the entire period. If Operation 4 lasted for 30 years and consisted of 24 000 soldiers, we cannot assume all 24 000 were deployed for all 30 years. If need be, we can assume each soldier stayed for 1 year.

I assume I should generate a period, and divide number of soldiers by number of days.

```
gen duration = End - Start
```

However, I do not know where to go from here. Any advice on how to (a) identify the number of soldiers (on average) deployed in any given year and (b) a clear way to graph this would be deeply appreciated.

PS: one problem in the past with regards to graphing operations is that some begin on the same day.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler than you fear, but you need a different data structure. Consider that the number of soldiers abroad increases when an operation starts and decreases when it ends. Whether they are the same people or different is immaterial if you just want to count soldiers. Alternatively, you give no information on which to base calculations of the number of *different* soldiers.

The technique here is written up within [this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0068) but the essence is conveyed by its title alone. Given the results, graphing is immediate using `line`; its `connect(J)` option may seem congenial.

```
clear 
input Operation  str10(sStart sEnd) Soldiers
1    "24.03.1999"    "14.01.2001"     447
2    "15.05.2004"    "03.03.2009"     880
3    "19.12.2006"    "24.01.2014"     4390
end 

foreach v in Start End { 
    gen `v' = daily(s`v', "DMY") 
    drop s`v' 
} 

expand 2 
bysort Operation: gen Date = cond(_n == 1, Start, End) 
by Operation: gen Status = (_n == 1) - (_n == 2)

format Date %td 
list 

sort Date Status 

gen Total = sum(Status * Soldiers) 
bysort Date : replace Total = Total[_N] 

list Date Status Soldiers Total, sep(0)  

     +---------------------------------------+
     |      Date   Status   Soldiers   Total |
     |---------------------------------------|
  1. | 24mar1999        1        447     447 |
  2. | 14jan2001       -1        447       0 |
  3. | 15may2004        1        880     880 |
  4. | 19dec2006        1       4390    5270 |
  5. | 03mar2009       -1        880    4390 |
  6. | 24jan2014       -1       4390       0 |
     +---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: When I run the `foreach` loop (with the dataset in question), I get the return code 110 (`Start already defined`). Would you advice me to use the label define or the replace command instead, or is there another way? Should I convert Start and End to strings as you did [here](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/6702-converting-dates-to-strings-i-e-swimming-upriver)?

FYI, the loop did work with the sample data provided in my original posting.

Comment: The example is self-contained. Sorry, but I  can't possibly give oracular advice on code you don't show us and a dataset we can't see. You need to post a new question with enough code and data for us to reproduce your problem.